# Create a basic custom tactic in Z3

Tags: c++, z3

In reference to the [How to implement a custom simplify tactic in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260893/how-to-implement-a-custom-simplify-tactic-in-z3)
 question, it's not clear to me the procedure to follow to create a tactics and make it available.

As far as i can understand i can add a file [let's assume my_tactics.cpp, my_tactics.h] inside src/tactics. Is it possible to add these additional files as a tactics and patch z3 to use it.

Sequence of steps to follow to add a new tactics would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. After adding new files, you need to re-run `python scripts/mk_make.py` for the build system to pick up the new files and to check their dependencies and to add them to the Makefile. If you add a new directory that is not part of any of the other submodules, you will also have to add a new component in scripts/mk_project.py. If you use the new CMake-based build system, please submit a new issue on GitHub as it's probably the first time someone tries that.